# how to put an array in the same cell in exceljs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, exceljs

i am getting a report and this report comes as below.

```
"reports": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "operatorName": "string",
      "systemName": "string",
      "serverName": "string",
      "alertTypeName": "string",
      "procedureName": "string",
      "alertDate": "2023-04-02T06:55:59.446Z",
      "departmentName": "string",
      "noticeTypeName": "string",
      "ticket": "string",
      "alertCount": 1,
      "alertDetail": "string",
      "actions": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "processId": 3,
          "actionTypeName": "string",
          "actionDescription": "string",
          "actionDate": "2023-04-02T06:55:59.446Z"
        }]]
```

And I export this report with the following excel service.

```
    /* Get Data from Json */

    let columnsArray: any[];
    for (const key in json) {
      if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        columnsArray = Object.keys(json[key]);
      }
    }

    /* Add Data */

    data.forEach((element : any) => {

      const eachRow: any[] = [];
      columnsArray.forEach((column) => {
        eachRow.push(element[column]);
      });


      if (element.isDeleted === 'Y') {
        const deletedRow = worksheet.addRow(eachRow);
        deletedRow.eachCell((cell) => {
          cell.font = {name: 'Calibri', family: 4, size: 11, bold: false, strike: true};
        });
      } else {
        worksheet.addRow(eachRow);
      }
    });

    worksheet.addRow([]);

  
    /* Save Excel */

    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data: ArrayBuffer) => {
      const blob = new Blob([data], {type: EXCEL_TYPE});
      fs.saveAs(blob, excelFileName + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
    });

  }
}
```

But I can't get the actions column as I want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJgop.png)

I want to see the actions array in the same cell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMNHO.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actions array must be transformed into a string. You must use "\n" to return new line.

```
const eachRow: any[] = [];
columnsArray.forEach((column) => {
  if (column === 'actions') {
    const actions = element[column].map((action: any) => {
      //format each action here. I you want all object, try:
      //return JSON.stringify(action)
      return `${action.actionTypeName} (${action.actionDate})`;
    }).join('\n');
    eachRow.push(actions);
  } else {
    eachRow.push(element[column]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. It worked !